# How to do reverse engineering in ASP.NET Core with IdentityDbContext<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have an existing database with Identity DB context model in it. When I reverse engineer it, it creates a context deriving from `DbContext` - but I want it to derive from `IdentityDbContext`.

Comment: So just update the generated C# class and - done!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.